# How to input elements in the array and then traverse them

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

How to input elements in the array and then traverse them?

Comment: What is `firstNode.sort(head, c)`?

Comment: actually i can't iterate within the method it has to be fully recursive. And firstNode.sort(head, c)- c is by mistake assume it a recursive call as firstNode.sort(head).

Answer (score 0):

```
public LinkedList<T> sort() {
    return sort(this.getNext());
}

public LinkedList<T> sort(LinkedList<T> head) {
    if (head == null) {
        this.setNext(null);
        return this;
    }

    sortedHead = head.sort();
    if (this.getData().compareTo(sortedHead.getData()) < 0) {
        this.setNext(sortedHead);
        return this;
    } else {
        sortedHead.setNext(this.sort(sortedHead.getNext()));
        return sortedHead;
    }
}
```